# Thread without sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm pretty new using Threads and I just did a little program to understand how it works. As a example a did a prime numbers exercise, the program is running perfectly but what I have discovered is that if I don't use sleep(), the order of the numbers change everytime I press run (without changing the code). So why is happening that?

```
    class Prime extends ThreadDemo implements Runnable 
    {
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=2;i<=20;i++)
        {
            if(prime(i))
            {
                System.out.printf ("Prime No.= %d \n",i);
            }
        }
    }
    }

    class notPrime extends ThreadDemo implements Runnable
    {
       int number= 0;
       public void run()
       {
           prime(number);
       }
    }

class ThreadDemo
{
    public boolean prime(int start_value)
    {
        for(int i=2; i<start_value; i++)
        {
           if(start_value%i == 0)
           {
               System.err.printf ("No. Prime = %d \n", start_value);
               return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Prime th1 = new Prime();
        Thread childOne = new Thread(th1);
        childOne.start();
        notPrime th2 = new notPrime();
        Thread childTwo = new Thread(th2);
        childTwo.start();   
    }
}
```

This is the result after I pressed run:

[image: This is the result after I pressed run]

This is the result after pressing again run:

[image: This is the result after pressing again run]

Comment: What is a prime number?

Comment: And where is the sleep that you mention?

Comment: Hint: it is not before a thread t1 is scheduled before t2 that it will run before t2; what is more, you can schedule between threads while they are still running

Comment: I 'm NOT using sleep. That's why I came to this question.

Comment: @derMarco See my answer. It will fix your problem and give you a better understanding of why this happens

Comment: IMO, @Dogs's answer is best because it says _why_ you get a different interleaving of results each time your program runs.  If you want things to always be done in the same order, then you should do them in the same thread.  Threads are used when you have two or more independent things that can be done at the same time, and it doesn't matter what order they finish.  When you make one thread wait for another, that's called _synchronization_.  Some synchronization is needed in any multi-threaded program, but the more synchronization you use, the less benefit you get from multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why this happens :

1. Your prime method is not synchronized.
2. Even if you synchronize the prime method, you are passing different instances of ThreadDemo to your threads. Locks are obtained on objects. If two threads are passed two different objects of ThreadDemo, each thread will lock its own instance of ThreadDemo thus allowing the Threads to run in parallel.

There are a couple of changes you need to make to your code to make sure that the same ThreadDemo is used for both your threads.

```
class NotPrimeRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ThreadDemo threadDemo;
    int number = 0;

    public NotPrimeRunnable(ThreadDemo threadDemo) {
        this.threadDemo = threadDemo;
    }

    public void run() {
        threadDemo.prime(number);
    }
}

class PrimeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private ThreadDemo threadDemo;

    public PrimeRunnable(ThreadDemo threadDemo) {
        this.threadDemo = threadDemo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (threadDemo.prime(i)) {
                System.out.printf("Prime No.= %d \n", i);
            }
        }
    }

}

class ThreadDemo {
    public synchronized boolean prime(int start_value) {
        for (int i = 2; i < start_value; i++) {
            if (start_value % i == 0) {
                System.err.printf("No. Prime = %d \n", start_value);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadDemo runnableTask = new ThreadDemo();
        PrimeRunnable th1 = new PrimeRunnable(runnableTask);
        Thread childOne = new Thread(th1);
        childOne.start();
        NotPrimeRunnable th2 = new NotPrimeRunnable(runnableTask);
        Thread childTwo = new Thread(th2);
        childTwo.start();
    }
}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: @derMarco Don't forget to upvote. An accepted answer without an upvote looks really odd ;)

Comment: I accepted but I can't voteup because I don't have more than 15 points :( sorry

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that *threads run in parallel*. When you create a bunch of threads, these threads all start doing things at the same time, and it's a race to see which ones finish first. This isn't deterministic, and sometimes the threads will finish in a different order.

The reason sleep could change this is that sleep will give the threads you created first a head start.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia defines thread as: "In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler".

Schedulers are software modules that run in the SO Kernel and manages the processes and threads execution. Schedulers use time-division multiplexing (as in multitasking) algorithms to ensure that all threads and process will be able to execute. One of the scheduler`s characteristics in SOs such as Windows, Mac OS and Linux is that the CPU switches between different software threads. As stated in Wikipedia: "This context switching generally happens frequently enough that the user perceives the threads or tasks as running at the same time."

Based on these considerations, we can explain your software behavior. Non-real time Operating System such as windows and MAC OSx, and many Linux distributions use scheduler algorithms that are non deterministic, so we cant predict the execution order of the threads, then it`s likely every time you execute you are going to get a different result regarding your text output order.

When you use sleep between the threads execution, it seems that the time amount chosen is enough to th1 execute completely before th2 starts. So the output is shown in the correct order.